# Getting full result set and returning NULL if needed

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables like this:

```
tableA
-------
skillId | characterId

tableB
-------
skillId | skillName
```

I need to select all rows in tableB and all rows in tableA where the characterId = 123, but also return NULL if the characterId is not in tableA

So the results would look like this:

```
charID    SkillName
-------------------
123       Jumping
123       Running
NULL      RangedAttack
123       MeleeWeapon
NULL      AutomaticWeapon
123       Handgun
NULL      EarthMagic
NULL      WaterMagic
```

I've tried this:

```
select a.characterId As charID, b.skillName AS SkillName
from tableA a
left join tableB b ON a.skillId = b.skillId
where characterId = 123
```

and this one:

```
select a.characterId As charID, b.skillName AS SkillName
from tableA a
full outer join tableB b ON a.skillId  = b.skillId
where characterId = 123
```

but both queries give me no results even though I know it should give me something.

Is there a proper way to get the results I need?

Thanks!

Comment: you should use a `full join` and move the `where` condition to the `join` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `left join` is in the wrong order:

```
select a.characterId As charID, b.skillName
from tableB b left join
     tableA a
     on a.skillid = b.skillId and a.characterId = 123;
```

If you want all the skills in `TableB`, then that should be the first table in the `left join`.